# Long title in the margin

Tags: formatting, margins, titles

I have formatted my `\subsubsection` title :

```latex
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
[block]
{\vspace{0.1cm}\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}
{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont SECTION\ \thesubsubsection}
{0.3em}
{\leading{18pt}\bfseries\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}[\vskip 0.5ex \titlerule]

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
```

But for a long title, here is the result :

[image]

As you can see, the title goes into the margin.

Does anyone know how to avoid this ? I would like my title to be on two lines, as this :

[image]

Here is my code :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[cam,width=17.5truecm,height=25.54truecm,center,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{leading}
\leading{12.8pt}

\lineskiplimit=-100pt\relax

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{BCBDC0}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
[block]
{\vspace{0.1cm}\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}
{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont SECTION\ \thesubsubsection}
{0.3em}
{\leading{18pt}\bfseries\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}[\vskip 0.5ex \titlerule]

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}


\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Affectation du commerce entre Etats membres}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
[block]
{\vspace{0.1cm}\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont\raggedright} % <------ Added \raggedright, here
{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont SECTION\ \thesubsubsection}
{0.3em}
{\leading{18pt}\bfseries\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}[\vskip 0.5ex \titlerule]

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
```

Comment: Hello ! Thanks  for your help ! Unfortunately this is not working...

Comment: Ouuups : It is actually working ! Thank you !